# TFS2012 - Access denied on copying diagnostic activity logs

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a problem with TFS2012 builds which I can't seem to figure out nor find any solution for.

**Setup:**

Separate SQL server, separate TFS Application server (TFSAT01 / WinSvr08R2) and separate build machine (TFSBLD01 / Win7x64).

Drop share created on TFSAT01 - R/W acess granted to the two computers in our domain: TFSAT01$ and TFSBLD01$ (According to #8 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb778394.aspx)

The build controller is configured on the TFS app. server TFSAT01.

The build agents are running on the build machine TFSBLD01.

**Problem:**

My CI build does complete and does copy all binaries to the drop share.

**But** I keep getting one error under  *Other Errors and Warnings* in the build output window which says: "An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Access to the path '\TFSAT01\Drops\PRODUCT-CI\PRODUCT-CI_20130211.16\Logs\ActivityLog.xml' is denied.". The ActivityLog.xml is indeed written and I can access it.

Any ideas to why I get this error even though it seems that the share is configured with the proper access rights?

**Note:**
I can get around this error by specifying a user-account for the build agent to use (also with R/W access rights to the drop share) - but I would rather if I could stick with the default NetworkService credentials used by the build controller and agents.

Comment: Could you provide r/w access to Network Service (build controller account) instead of TFSAT01$ on the drop location.

Comment: I can't specifically add the TFSAT01\NetworkService account to the share. But I assume that this is what I effectively do by adding the TFSAT01$ - where the $ indicates all local machine accounts.

Comment: Subtle difference - Network Service is a local identity and the $ account is that same identity seen outside of that machine. Use "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" or "Network Service" to add and let us know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Update: just adding "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" via the "Share with-->Specific people" yields no result - the account gets added, but when reviewing the share permissions the account is simply not listed.

Comment: Update 2: I tried to delete the share, re-create it, and just add the DOMAIN\TFSAT01$ account with R/W access. This seems to work. Could be that the DOMAIN is the key factor here and initially giving access to just TFSAT01$ was what caused the share permission to be incorrect.

Comment: Update 3: ignore "Update 2" - that did not fix the problem (I tested it on the wrong share :(). Anyhow @allen I did manage to add "NETWORK SERVICE" via advanced sharing - and this seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Should resolve to the same sid though.

Answer (score 4):

Adding in resolution based on discussion in the comments

The build controller account needs to have R/W permissions on the drop location. The TFSAT01$ account was provisioned here while the build controller was configured as network service. Since these are not really the same account providing R/W permissions to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE is the required fix.

Answer (score 0):

The build controller must run under the same account which has R/W permissions on drop location. I recommend to use same user account for build agents and build controller.

Answer (score 0):

On TFS build controller, right click on the XAML Build Configuration > [your build service]

Click on "Stop the service"

Click "change" button under Run service as: section

Use a user who has access to both TFS repository & the drop location.

p.s. using TFS 2015