# TFS2013: An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Internal Server Error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I've read other articles similar to this such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814641/tfs2012-access-denied-on-copying-diagnostic-activity-logs) but I have been unable to resolve this on my TFS 2013 config.  I upgraded TFS 2012 Update 3 to TFS 2013 then moved it to another server as I needed a setup with SQL Server 2012.  I didn't have any issues with TFS 2012 but after upgrading to TFS 2013 I'm getting an error in the build system.  The builds complete as "Partially Succeeded" as the actual builds complete but I get the following error:

> An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Internal Server Error

There is a similar inquiry on Microsoft Connect [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794980/after-upgrading-to-tfs-2013-preview-all-builds-now-partial-succeed-with-errors) but I don't know how the OP resolved it.

I've checked permissions, added full control permissions to the user that the build service runs under, NETWORK SERVICE, etc.  I added this permission to various areas, I'm not sure exactly which one needs it i.e. the build folder, the drop folder, the TFS application tier area, or what.  I don't see any helpful information in the Windows Event Logs or TFS debug log.  I'm out of ideas on how to resolve this.

Any help would be appreciated.  And this TFS setup does not use Active Directory as I'm the sole user/developer in this config and small biz.

Thank you

**EDIT**

I installed SQL 2012, Visual Studio 2013, TFS 2013 to a new server, added one solution ran a build and the exact same errors occurred.  I'll have to open a case on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: note: I had same issue and found a solution - check the account that the build controller is running as (not the build agent, not the tfs service) it's what copies the final couple of log files to the drop folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a fix to this issue, however, after moving to a new server and installing SQL 2014 and TFS 2013 Update 2 and following this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx all is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a share folder, configure the share in the ComputerSettings. in the "Shared Folder" configure the Share in the Security Tab and the Publishment Options

Comment: Hello, please explain "configure the share in the ComputerSettings"

Comment: on the server there ist the computer management (execute compmgmt.msc) there is a node "Shared Folders"

Comment: Thanks, everything checks good there, not sure what's causing this still.  Working on moving to a fresh install on a different server.